# Is it possible to increment the value of a range of array elements by a constant without looping through the list?

Tags: python, loops, libraries

Are there any modules or libraries in python that could help me with this? I mean to do this with a complexity of O(1).

Comment: To add `1` to *n* elements you need to perform *n* operations. But you can *NumPy* array for a vectorized solution.

Comment: This sounds like you're taking the wrong approach to a coding challenge problem.

Comment: Most likely, you shouldn't be explicitly storing this array at all - you should find a different way to compute the results of whatever query operations you're supposed to support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `numpy` to do this

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> data = np.arange(10)
>>> data
array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
>>> data[2:6] += 5
>>> data
array([ 0,  1,  7,  8,  9, 10,  6,  7,  8,  9])
```

Comment: This performs the loop inside NumPy, looping over the array's buffer with minimal overhead. It beats a pure-Python loop, but the question sounds like the underlying problem needs an entirely different data structure.

Comment: But the complexity is not `O(1)` even when you use *NumPy* array. But a much faster and vectorized solution than using lists

Answer (score 0):

You can increment the value of a range of array elements by a constant without looping through the list making use of `Broadcasting` in numpy.

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html

But I don't think you can do this in O(1) which might be an NP-hard problem.